# HTTP PUT works in RESTClient but not in Postman or Python httplib

Tags: python, http, hadoop, hdfs

When I do a PUT request in RESTClient it works, but it fails in the *Postman* Chrome extension.

I need to call the Hadoop REST API. When I use `curl` all is okay, as with RESTClient. It fails when I use Python `httplib`, as with Postman.

Here is it working in RESTClient:
[image: RESTClient is OK]

Here is it failing in Postman:
[image: Postman failed]

It returns a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` with the message `op=NULL is not supported`.

How can I send this PUT request correctly with Python's `httplib`? For some reason `curl` is not suitable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the endpoint you're hitting requires an `op` argument to be provided in the query string. You have `?op=CREATE` in your RESTClient screenshot, but it doesn't appear in your Postman screenshot.

I notice also that in your RESTClient screenshot the server is responding with a redirect to add an *additional* parameter `overwrite=false`; you may need to add this parameter to your request in order for the operation to actually be carried out.

Comment: TKS. In the Postman, i add op argument first, then it change to this. Do you know how to query this with Python httplib. In fact, i just need to Put this request in Python.

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you already tried to do this with Python `httplib`; if you edit the question to include your code I'm happy to try to help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I see you asked about the Python solution as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716303/put-this-request-with-python-httplib . That's fine, but please close out this question since it's quite redundant with your new question.

Comment: Really Thanks.Your Answer has helped me.