# Put this request with Python httplib

Tags: python, rest, httplib

I want to put a request to HDFS REST API.

It works in the RESTClient.

But it failed when i translate it to Python edition( python httplib).

And i can't use this in Curl for some reason.

Anybody know httplib put, can help me translate it to Python edition?

Here is the RESTClient edition:

method: PUT

URL: http://www.somedomain.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/levi/4?op=CREATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
requests.put('http://www.somedomain.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/levi/4?op=CREATE')
```

With `httplib`:

```
import httplib

connection =  httplib.HTTPConnection('www.somedomain.com:50070')
connection.request('PUT', '/webhdfs/v1/levi/4?op=CREATE')

response = connection.getresponse()
```

Comment: Really Thanks.I was in a holiday, so the reply is late.